# Displaying custom message in login page when redirected by `AuthorizeAttribute`

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, httpcontext, authorize-attribute

I have written a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` to display message in the login page. Here is the code.

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            httpContext.Items["LoginFailMessage"] = Message;
        }

        return authorized;
    }
}
```

In my action I will do

```
[MyAuthorize(Message = "Please login to continue")]
public ActionResult Detail()
```

Now, I cannot access the item `HttpContext.Current.Items["LoginFailMessage"]` in my view. I realize that the problem is, the item exists only for one redirection call but authorization failure is causing more than one redirection.

So, is there a way I can solve the issue? From exactly where should I pass the message?

**Edit**

What I am trying to do is, suppose, an Anonymous user is allowed to see a short description of something.

With the description, there is a `edit` and a `detail` link. Both `edit` and `detail` requires the user to login. So, the user will be redirected to login page if clicks either.

If user clicks `edit` I will display a message `Please login to edit` and if clicks `detail` may be `please login to see detail` in the login page.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier for you to use the ModelState to do this, for example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model) {
    // .. check model state is valid
    if (AuthorizationService.Authorize(model.Username, model.Password)) {
        // .. user is authenticated
    }
    else {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login failed.");
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Then you can use the ValidationSummary() to show the error on the login page, or, pass the name of the username or password model property in the AddModelError call to use a ValidationMessage().

Comment: You have not answered what I asked. Perhaps my question is not clear enough.

Comment: You asked "From exactly where should I pass the message?".. I gave you an alternative which is much easier than writing your own Authorization attribute.

Comment: So, what message do you expect to see when the first time login page has appeared? I have edited the question with an `Action` example.

Comment: I see. Can you explain the reasoning behind what you're doing? I still think there is a better approach. I can't see why you would want to do that..